# Autofac Resolving MatchingLifetimeScope Collection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to resolve an IEnumerable of all services from a named scope, but that doesn't work, because services are also resolved from other named scopes.

**Example**

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterType<B>().As<IMyInterface>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("B");
containerBuilder.RegisterType<A>().As<IMyInterface>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("A");

IContainer container= containerBuilder.Build();

ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("A");
lifetimeScope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyInterface>>();
```

**throws** `DependencyResolutionException: Unable to resolve the type 'ConsoleApp2.B' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located.`

Is there a way to only resolve services from the current scope?

I am using **Autofac 6.0.0**

Comment: If you register a component with the InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope option, the runtime code will expect to find a life time scope tagged with the same string, otherwise an exception is raised. Your code will work only if you start a new life time scope from the first one ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope2 = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("B") and then you call Resolve on the latter.  If you want to have conditional registration you should look at the Named or Keyed options.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the version of Autofac you're using? This may be a bug.

Comment: I added the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It appears you've encountered a bug.** [There's a similar issue already open](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/969) for this; I'll add a repro of your specific case to the issue and update it to be flagged as a bug rather than an enhancement.

I'm unaware of any workarounds to solve this issue at the moment. Sorry.